Convert time_point -> Rep and back again (Rep -> time_point)
How to update date in a datepicker element. I have a int64_t attribute m_myDate that contains the date.

TimeSpan is a specialization of std::chrono::duration.
DateTime a specialization of std::chrono::time_point.

MainWindow.xaml.cpp
    ...
    void MainWindow::saveBtn_Click(IInspectable const& sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        dateTime = myDatePicker().Date();
        m_myDate = dateTime.time_since_epoch().count();
    }

    void MainWindow::loadBtn_Click(IInspectable const& sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        dateTime.time_since_epoch(std::chrono::nanoseconds(m_myDate)); // replace this with correct code
        myDatePicker().Date(dateTime);
    }
    ...

Environment
c++20
winui3
All files as a VS 2022 project
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsM8s08DJk30u5kAsOK-A6MOZ8YiSg?e=whhfzN

@TomHuntington
it seem like dateTime.time_since_epoch() do not take params or I am using the wrong  DateTime!
Error (active) E0140 too many arguments in function call DatePicker MainWindow.xaml.cpp 40

myDatePicker().Date(winrt::Windows::Foundation::DateTime{ winrt::Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan{m_myDate}} );

@TomHuntington
So far so good. But DatePicker do not get updated with the new value!
Is this code wrong?
myDatePicker().Date(dateTime);

Whether you want to set the date currently selected in the date picker after clicking the button? If so, you could try to use DatePicker.SelectedDate Property

    void MainWindow::saveBtn_Click(IInspectable const& sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        dateTime = myDatePicker().Date();
        m_myDate = dateTime.time_since_epoch().count();
        myTextBox().Text(to_hstring(m_myDate));
    }

    void MainWindow::loadBtn_Click(IInspectable const& sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args)
    {
        myDatePicker().SelectedDate(winrt::Windows::Foundation::DateTime{ winrt::Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan{m_myDate} });
        myDatePicker().UpdateLayout();
    }

See https://github.com/TirsvadGUI/Cpp.Winui3.Example-Controls/tree/master/src/DatePicker

If you've solved the issue, please do not forget the accept it as answer.
